# Graph API bug - posting links, missing description

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink

When posting a link on a page using the Graph API, the description is missing.

Might be related to this bug http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=14782.

Is this going to be fixed? Now I'm posting as feed/ instead, here the description is shown - but then there is no "share" button.

Any known workaround?

Comment: What code are you using to post?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is, and really it doesn't make much intuitive sense, but I've had success posting to the `PAGE_ID/links` feed, rather than identifying the page ID independently and then just posting to `graph.facebook.com/links`

Thus, I'm posting using:

```
curl -F 'access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN' \ 
-F 'link=LINK' \ 
-F 'name=TITLE' \ 
-F 'description=DESCRIPTION' \  
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/links
```

Rather than:

```
curl -F 'access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN' \ 
-F 'link=LINK' \ 
-F 'name=TITLE' \ 
-F 'description=DESCRIPTION' \ 
-F 'id=PAGE_ID' \
https://graph.facebook.com/links
```

In my testing, the former allows proper formatting of each of the elements, while the latter does not.  Both surface the share link.  I do not know why this is, but it works.

Hope this helps.